# VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates does not return controls with IsHitTestVisible set up to false

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, visualtreehelper

I am doing some experiments and I am trying to collect all elements which are placed under mouse pointer.

**XAML test code**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button
        x:Name="HitButton"
        Content="Test Button" />
    <Button
        x:Name="NotHitButton"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        Content="Test Button" />
</StackPanel>
```

To get coordinates of mouse pointer I use `PointerMoved`:

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

private void OnPointerMoved(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
{
    Point point = args.CurrentPoint.Position;
    IEnumerable<UIElement> elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(point, null, true);
    ...
}
```

This approach works, however, when a control has property `IsHitTestVisible` set up to `false`, `FindElementsInHostCoordinates` does not consider it even if I set up the third parameter `includeAllElements` of this method to `true`.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper#methods_) I would expect if I set the parameter `includeAllElements` to `true`, it should find all elements, including those controls which have `IsHitTestVisible` set up to `false`.

> includeAllElements [System.Boolean]
>
> true to include all elements that
>   intersect, including those elements considered to be invisible to hit
>   testing. false to find only visible, hit-testable elements. The
>   default is false.

Do I understand wrong way how `FindElementsInHostCoordinates` works? If so, is there any other way how to retrieve all controls at specific coordinates even if they have `IsHitTestVisible` set to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think the key point of this question is what are the "elements **considered to be invisible** to hit testing".

I'd think when we set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`, the element is not considered to be invisible, it's just invisible. And according to [Hit testing and input events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#hit-testing-and-input-events), the element meets following criteria is hit-testable.

> - The element's **Visibility** property value is **Visible**.
> - The element's **Background** or **Fill** property value is not null. A **null Brush** value results in transparency and hit test invisibility. (To make an element transparent but also hit testable, use a **Transparent** brush instead of **null**.)
> - If the element is a control, its **IsEnabled** property value must be **true**.
> - The element must have actual dimensions in layout. An element where either **ActualHeight** and **ActualWidth** are 0 won't fire input events.

So I think when a element's `Visibility` property value is `Collapsed` or its `Background` or `Fill` property value is `null` or its `IsEnabled` property value is `false`, the element is considered to be invisible. And I did a simple test.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border Name="Border" Width="200" Height="300" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid Name="Grid" Width="100" Height="250">
            <Rectangle Name="CollapsedRectangle" Fill="Azure" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Rectangle Name="NoFillRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
            <Button Name="Button" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,0,0">CLICK</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().PointerMoved += (s, e) =>
    {
        Point point = e.CurrentPoint.Position;
        IEnumerable<UIElement> elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(point, Border, false);

        foreach (var item in elements)
        {
            FrameworkElement feItem = item as FrameworkElement;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(feItem.Name);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
    };
}
```

When `includeAllElements` parameter is set to `false`, the output is like

```
Border
-----------------------------------------
Border
-----------------------------------------
Border
-----------------------------------------
```

And when `includeAllElements` parameter is set to `true`, the output is like

```
Border
-----------------------------------------
Grid
Border
-----------------------------------------
...
NoFillRectangle
Grid
Border
-----------------------------------------
...
Grid
Border
-----------------------------------------
Border
-----------------------------------------
```

So it seems that `includeAllElements` parameter only takes effect when  element's `Background` or `Fill` property value is `null`. Not sure if this is by design. **Maybe only the elements whose `Background` or `Fill` property value is `null` is considered to be invisible.**

Comment: That is very interesting research, thanks a lot. Do you happen to know if there is any alternative approach how to find all elements in a position besides `FindElementsInHostCoordinates` which could find really all elements without any obstacles?

Answer (score 1):

[@ZORRO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42314641/5254458)'s observation is mostly correct.

XAML hit-testing is based on the philosophy that if an element occupies space on screen and "***produces ink***" then it hit-tests.

The main question is around what produces ink:

- For elements that have a `Brush` (the vast majority), any **non-null** brush is considered something that **produces ink**, even if the brush doesn't produce visible pixels.  For example *a `SolidColorBrush` with color "Transparent" **still produces ink***.  **Only a null brush does not produce ink**.
- There are some special elements such as `SwapChainPanel` and `MediaElement` that don't have a brush but can ***still produce ink***.
- The Opacity property is not considered here

So as long as one of the above is true, the element **still produces ink** even if Opacity equals 0.

What all this means is when the `includeAllElements` parameter is set to true, elements that **don't produce ink** are considered for hit-testing. In this case, as long as the element meets the spatial requirements (point/rect intersects the element bounds), then it and its ancestors are included in the results.

BTW, we are working with content team to refine this document to make it clear.